# OpenCV doesn't come with "external" libraries

Tags: python, opencv, dependency-management, opencv3.0

I tried [this example](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html) from the OpenCV website:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# changed the image names from box* since the sample images were not given on the site
img1 = cv2.imread('burger.jpg',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('burger.jpg',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.SIFT()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# Need to draw only good matches, so create a mask
matchesMask = [[0,0] for i in xrange(len(matches))]

# ratio test as per Lowe's paper
for i,(m,n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        matchesMask[i]=[1,0]

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0),
                   singlePointColor = (255,0,0),
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = 0)

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches,None,**draw_params)

plt.imshow(img3,),plt.show()
```

Executing the example, viz. `python test.py`, gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    sift = cv2.SIFT()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'
```

I had installed OpenCV from source, building manually. All modules were built by `make`, if I recall correctly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561910/opencv-python-cant-use-surf-sift) suggested that I install `opencv-contrib` from its GitHub repository. I did, and I still get this error.

My system is Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855753/pythonopencv-3-cant-use-sift

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561910/opencv-python-cant-use-surf-sift

Comment: cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is applicable, but at some point they stopped supporting SIFT in the later versions of opencv I believe due to the fact that it is patented or something related (source?), however an alternate is to use ORB which will have a similar effect.

You could try something like this:

```
from cv2 import ORB as SIFT
```

However in the event that you get an import error this also might work for you:

```
SIFT = cv2.ORB_create
```

If you insert those near the top of your file, then *likely* you can leave "SIFT" as it is throughout the file (well more or less, you get the idea, basically replace the cv2.Sift() with sift = SIFT() and you should be in better shape.)